# BSOD - Hollow file with actual size

Tags: windows-7, bsod, visual-studio-2012, ide, visual-c++

I was working in VS 2012 on a cpp file when I got a BSOD.

When the pc turned back on, I couldn't see the contents of the file again. These are the details:

1. when I open the file I was working on from within Solution Explorer, it appears me as a blank notepad file
2. when I try to open the file with IDE editor, it says that the file can't be opened.
3. When I go to the project's folder I can see the cpp file as having 7Ko, just as before the BSOD. I think the information is still there. Maybe there's a EOL interfering somewhere.
4. When I open it with a HEX editor, I only see groups of 00.

Please help me, I worked a lot at this file, and I'd prefer not to loose it.

Thank you.

Comment: Groups of 00 does suggest that the file is filled with NUL (`\0`) bytes. This suggests that the file was corrupted. Do you happen to have any version control for your project/solution?

Comment: I don't have any version control. To be future-proof, is git a good program?

Comment: `git` is a pretty nice program for version control. There are many alternatives though (i.e. decentralized vs centralized VCS), and it's difficult to explain at length here. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for your file loss. You might want to also check if [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is able to retrieve previous versions of the file.